# I am trying to generate a Visualforce page that will allow me to geolocate a staff person when they submit a contact report at an account

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to generate a Visualforce page that will allow me to geolocate a staff person when they submit a contact report at an account and then store their GPS coords from the mobile device.

I found this post which gave me a page to do this.. almost
..   https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/10/winter-13-using-apex-and-soql-with-geolocation.html

and I have created this page with an input form using..

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="New Report" columns="1">

    <apex:inputField value="{!account.contact_report__r.date_of_shift__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!account.contact_report__r.start_time__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!account.contact_report__r.finish_time__c}" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!account.contact_report__r.geolocation__Latitude__s}" id="contactlat" />
    <apex:inputField value="{!account.contact_report__r.geolocation__Longitude__s}" id="contactlong" />
```

but I am getting this error..

```
Error: Invalid field contact_report__r for SObject Account
```

I am sure the problem is this

```
!account.contact_report__r.date_of_shift__c
```

but cant see where I may be wrong (I am a beginner :)   and have tried various combinations of underscore c and r to no avail.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems more related to master-detail (parent-child) relationship naming than geolocation.

It sounds like Contact_Report is a child object of Account meaning that there can be zero to many Contact_Report objects for a single Account. If this is the situation, your page and controller should be focussed on the Contact_Report object and all you need to do is to set the Account ID when you save the contact report.

(Assuming the previous paragraph is correct, you probably added a Master-Detail or Lookup Relationship from Contact_Report to Account. Click on that relationship to view it and you will see a "Child Relationship Name" that by convention is usually a plural. For a single account that name with a `__r` appended is a list of Contact_Report objects provided the Contact_Report objects are queried together with the Account.)

See [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) for more detail about the naming.